# toggle and change background colour

Tags: javascript

I am trying to both toggle and change the colour of the div i am toggling background colour. How do i do this. I have followed a example i have seen online, and just added to my original toggle script, but i cannot seem to get this to work.

```
        //turn entire div into toggle

  function toggle_visibility(id) {

            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if (e.style.display == "block" || e.style.display == "")
                e.style.display = "none";
            else
                e.style.display = "block";
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }else{

        e.style.display = "none";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
        return( false );
        }
```

Comment: The first `if` is missing...

Comment: The first `else` block have two statements, should use `{}`.

Comment: @Monroe does it work now? :)

Comment: @GG. unfortunately not

Comment: @Monroe Try this code `function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if(e.style.display == "block" || e.style.display == "") {
        e.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        e.style.display = "block";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}`

Comment: @Tushar thank you that works. it is weird as that changes the background colour of the entire page, but toggle_visibility is called on a specific on a div. If i was to add another else statement is it possible to change it back

Comment: Oops! `document.body.style.backgroundColor`. You want `e.style....`

Comment: @Tushar thank you for all your help. I now have it changing between two different colours. Just need to work out how not to change the full bg. Thank you

Comment: hey you should run you code through something like http://jshint.com/ it'll warn you about some mistakes, like the one you just had

Comment: @user3 oh thank you for that tip